# Is there a way to save a CSV file that has been modified by another function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter, export-to-csv

I am new to programming in Python, and I am trying to make a CLI that allows users to filther through csv data with some pre-defined commands with Pandas and Click. I currently have the options for users to list the original data and filter the data by color. My list() and color() functions seem to work how I want them to.

I want to add a save() function that allows users to export the data to a new CSV file after it has been filtered, but I can't figure out how to pass the data that has been filtered to the save() function.

This is the code I currently have.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import click #imports click for CLI commands 
import pandas as pd #import for pandas 

df = pd.read_csv('dogs.csv') #reads the original data set.
@click.group() #creates a group 
@click.help_option('--help', help='displays the list of available commands') #adds help option

def cli():
    pass

##this shows the original list of cats 
@click.command() 
def list():
    """Simple command that lists all original dogs."""
    click.echo(f"{df}")

### this lists the filtered list of colored cats 
@click.command() 
@click.option("--color", prompt="Enter the desired color", help="The color of the dogs")
def color(color):
    """Simple command that filters dogs based on COLOR."""
    color = color.lower()
    new_df = df[df['Color'].str.contains(color)]
    click.echo(f"{new_df}")
    
### i want this to save the changes to a new csv file 
@click.command()
@click.option("--save",  help="Saves the file")
def save(save):
    """Simple command that saves the filtered list of dogs."""
    # i am lost here 
    save = new_df
    click.echo(f"{save}")
    
    
### add all commands to group 
cli.add_command(list)
cli.add_command(color)
cli.add_command(save)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

I tried making **new_df** a global variable which did not work. I also tried returning **new_df,** but that did not work either.

I am trying to pass the filteed results from the **color()** function into **save()** so that I can export the filtered changes as a csv. Is this something I can do in Python?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to save the result of `color` command to a file (or if isn't any file provides, just print it to the screen):

```py
import click  # imports click for CLI commands
import pandas as pd  # import for pandas

# sample dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Bob", "Rex"], "Color": ["White", "Brown"]})


@click.group()  # creates a group
@click.help_option(
    "--help", help="displays the list of available commands"
)  # adds help option
def cli():
    pass


##this shows the original list of cats
@click.command()
def list():
    """Simple command that lists all original dogs."""
    click.echo(f"{df}")


### this lists the filtered list of colored cats
@click.command()
@click.option(
    "--color", prompt="Enter the desired color", help="The color of the dogs"
)
@click.option("--save", default=None, type=click.Path())
def color(color, save):
    """Simple command that filters dogs based on COLOR."""
    new_df = df[df.Color.str.lower() == color.lower()]
    if not save:
        click.echo(f"{new_df}")
    else:
        new_df.to_csv(save, index=False)
        click.echo(f"Dataframe saved to {save}")


### add all commands to group
cli.add_command(list)
cli.add_command(color)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

---

This will add option to the `color` command:

```
$ python3 example.py color --help
Usage: example.py color [OPTIONS]

  Simple command that filters dogs based on COLOR.

Options:
  --color TEXT  The color of the dogs
  --save PATH
  --help        Show this message and exit.
```

and then you can invoke it with:

```
$ python3 example.py color --save data.csv
Enter the desired color: white
Dataframe saved to data.csv
```

saves `data.csv`:

```
Name,Color
Bob,White
```